# Qt Creator duplicate entries in makefile LIBS line

Tags: c++, qt, makefile, qt-creator, qmake

I have a Qt application developed in Qt Creator 3.3 (Windows 7) using **Qt 5.4.0** which was (and still is) working fine. I also installed **Qt 5.4.1** parallel to it with kit definition of its own which does not fully work.

The problem that I'm having is that in the autogenerated makefiles of the **5.4.1** build, I have a duplicate *LIBS* entry for both Qt versions. Below are the relavant parts of the generated makefiles (I added linebreaks for readability)

**Qt 5.4.0**

```
LIBS          = glu32.lib opengl32.lib gdi32.lib user32.lib shell32.lib
                /LIBPATH:
                C:\cpplib\qt-5.4\5.4\msvc2010_opengl\lib
                C:\cpplib\qt-5.4\5.4\msvc2010_opengl\lib\qtmain.lib
                C:\cpplib\qt-5.4\5.4\msvc2010_opengl\lib\Qt5WinExtras.lib
                C:\cpplib\qt-5.4\5.4\msvc2010_opengl\lib\Qt5Widgets.lib
                C:\cpplib\qt-5.4\5.4\msvc2010_opengl\lib\Qt5Gui.lib
                C:\cpplib\qt-5.4\5.4\msvc2010_opengl\lib\Qt5Network.lib
                C:\cpplib\qt-5.4\5.4\msvc2010_opengl\lib\Qt5Core.lib
```

**Qt 5.4.1**

```
LIBS          = glu32.lib opengl32.lib gdi32.lib user32.lib shell32.lib
                /LIBPATH:
                C:\cpplib\qt-5.4\5.4.1\msvc2010_opengl_64\lib
                C:\cpplib\qt-5.4\5.4.1\msvc2010_opengl_64\lib\qtmain.lib
                C:\cpplib\qt-5.4\5.4.1\msvc2010_opengl_64\lib\Qt5WinExtras.lib
                C:\cpplib\qt-5.4\5.4.1\msvc2010_opengl_64\lib\Qt5Widgets.lib
                C:\cpplib\qt-5.4\5.4.1\msvc2010_opengl_64\lib\Qt5Gui.lib
                C:\cpplib\qt-5.4\5.4.1\msvc2010_opengl_64\lib\Qt5Network.lib
                C:\cpplib\qt-5.4\5.4.1\msvc2010_opengl_64\lib\Qt5Core.lib
                /LIBPATH:
                C:\cpplib\qt-5.4\5.4\msvc2010_opengl_64\lib
                C:\cpplib\qt-5.4\5.4\msvc2010_opengl_64\lib\Qt5Core.lib
```

If I remove the last two lines everything works fine, but obviously only until the next time I run `qmake`, then they are written again. I could not find any menu in Qt Creator and settings file in my `AppData` folder related to these entries so I have no idea where all these values come from. There are no additional `LIBS` entries in my project file and of course, it is the same project for both builds.

**Note:**
I should add that the last file can't be found because I do not have a **64bit Qt 5.4.0** build on my machine. Otherwise the additional entry would not really matter as it is simply not needed.

Comment: I am also seeing this, QT 5.7.1 in QT Creator 4.2.0 on Gentoo 64-bit. It didn't used to be this way, but after some moving around of files, it occurs quite often.